# Can't ping Ubuntu Server 18.04 ⟷ router

Tags: networking, 18.04, virtualization, ping, router

I have to create a virtual server as a school project using a VM. I chose Ubuntu 18.04. The project includes 2 routers and 3 PCs. One PC is my laptop, the other two are virtual ones like the 2 routers. My problem is I can ping from router 1 to PC 1 (virtual) and from router 2 to PC 2, but I can't reach PC 1 from router 2 and vice versa. Furthermore I cannot reach PC 2 by pinging it from PC 1.

Comment: What hosts the VMs?

Comment: We need more informations. - About subnets... - which router has which interface and ip's - which pc's have which ip's - a simple network and project plan if possible - route table of each pc's